# In ASP.net C# is there a way I can pass control to my CS from Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to implement Facebook logins into my application as per following this guide:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0

The facebook stuff is all working fine :)

However after the facebook authentication completes, I want to pass all the appropriate variables to my C# code behind the webpage for entry into my DB, before redirecting onto the next portion of the signup process.

I am aware on how to do that using asp tags in the HTML like :

```
<asp:ImageButton id=ctrlNext runat="server" ImageUrl="Btn_Next.gif" onclick="ctrlNext_Click"></asp:ImageButton>
```

But if control is currently within a javascript function after completing from Facebook - I dont want the user to then have to manually click a button to continue - ideally they Click the facebook login button, I call the facebook APIs and then the page redirects having stored the information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [PageMethods and Ajax](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/).

Make sure to include the following using statment:

```
using System.Web.Services;
```

Your PageMethod would be something like:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string fbLogin()
{
  /* Do your DB Magic Here */
}
```

Use jQuery.ajax method:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // Logged into your app and Facebook.
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "YouPageName.aspx/fbLogin",
       data: "{}",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(msg) {
       // Do something interesting here.
       //Like a redirect 
          document.location.href = "http://www.somewherecool.com/newPage.aspx";
     }
    });
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
  } else {
    // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
    // they are logged into this app or not.
  }
});
```

This is just the bare bones to get you started. Don't forget to flesh out error handling etc.

**HOWEVER**

As you are going to do a redirect you're kind of defeating the purpose of going AJAX. There are a few ways of using javascript to get a page to post back. The quickest, easiest and hackiest way of doing it is having an asp button with a normal serverside click handler that is hidden via CSS. Then use javascipt (jquery) in the following example to click the button.

**Button**

```
<asp:ImageButton id="ctrlNext" style="display:none" runat="server" ImageUrl="Btn_Next.gif" onclick="ctrlNext_Click"></asp:ImageButton>
```

**javascript**

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // Logged into your app and Facebook.
    //CLick the button
     $("#<%=ctrlNext.ClientID%>").click();
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
  } else {
    // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
    // they are logged into this app or not.
  }
});
```

Comment: If this is static.....and 2 users try to log in simulatenously, wont they be using the same instance of this function and therefore get tangled up?

Comment: Also - when i try the [WebMethod] attribute throws an error saying assembly reference is missing?

Comment: See this article on why WebMethods have to be static: http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/. Also keep in mind that it is the method that is static, not the class, i.e. the page class. So no multiple users won't get "tangled" up.

Comment: Sometimes you'll find assembly references aren't included in the using statments that you want to be using. In your code in visual studio your `WebMethod` statement is probably underlined with a red wavy line. Click on it and a little blue "hint" should appear under `W`. Hover over that and click the icon that appears, select `using System.Web.Services;` which will then add it to the using statment at the top of the page. This technique can come in handy when adding things like `linq` and `StringBuilders` to the page when you can't remember the exact using statement to use.

Comment: Jon - I assume using this method - forcing a URL change is not actually possible from the server side using Response.Redirect(url); as I think the static page has no page context? How would I best achieve this redirect?

Comment: Correct, you won't be able to do a server-side redirect. However in the success function of the ajax call you could use javascript. I'll update the ansewer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58204/discussion-between-renegadeandy-and-jon-p).

Answer (score 0):

In general,(assuming you're using MVC) you need to make a post to a controller method in your application that will save the data. See [jQuery .post() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

If not using MVC, something like [AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx) might work.  Been so long since I've done not MVC work I'm not up on what's the most current way to do AJAX there.

Comment: I am not using MVC! However I assume posting back to my .cs will still work.

Comment: it's definitely still possible without using MVC. edited above

Answer (score 0):

In this code, where it says "// Logged into your app and Facebook." you can call your controller method and pass token and other needed parameters, which in turn will save the parameters to DB and redirect to your home or launching page.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // Logged into your app and Facebook.
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
  } else {
    // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
    // they are logged into this app or not.
  }
});
```

**Edit 1**-

In WebForms, you could write js like below and call it from FB.login  function valSubmit() { var doc = document.forms[0]; doc.submit(); return true; }  where form[0] is your actual form. You will get a postback in CS code

Comment: What syntax would you use to call a function that lives on the server side ?

Comment: In WebForms, you could write js like below and call it from FB.login                                                                                     <script language="javascript">
function valSubmit() {
var doc = document.forms[0];

doc.submit();
return true;
 }
</script>                                                                          where form[0] is your actual form. You will get a postback in CS code.

Comment: It is a webform, so this looks promising - but "-" wont get me far ;)

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, just make a controller and post to the controller method with jquery ajax.

Or, In WebForms

Create a Generic HTTP handler e.g.

```
LoginStuff.ashx
```

Create a method on the controller that returns a string and return a JSON string using the JavascriptSerializer class.

Then call the ASHX handler the same way, jQuery Ajax.

You can post data to the ashx handler, then the ajax Success method on the javascript side will get back the JSON object your method returned.